# Referencing my own object: When is it allowed and when is it not?

Tags: c++, object

It looks like as if I can sometimes reference my own object and sometimes not - for example:

```
#ifndef TILE_H
#define TILE_H

#include "position.h"
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using std::vector;
using std::pair;
namespace Game {
class tile
{
public:
    tile(int x, int y, int value);
    void savePosition();
    void updatePosition(int x, int y);
    void updatePosition(gridSquare g);
    vector<pair<gridSquare, int>> serialize();
    bool isEqualTo(tile rhs /* why is this allowed? */ ){ 
       return position.x == rhs.position.x && position.y == rhs.position.y && value == rhs.value;
    }
public:

    gridSquare position;
    int value;

    gridSquare previousPosition;
    tile mergedFrom; // but this not?

};
}
#endif // TILE_H
```

Shouldn't both be not allowed? The second one throws an "incomplete type" error, but the first one does not throw any error of any sort, while it still references a perhaps incomplete class. What is happening? Why is the first one allowed but the second one not? Is it because the first one is not *used* until the class has completed definition?

Comment: Ignoring the c++ angle; it is not normal to permit recursive structure definitions; for example `struct a { int b,c; struct a d; };` which is a de-cluttered version of what you are trying to do.  That said, it is always worth trying every imaginable version of the *standard* that your compiler supports, just to see if one works.

Comment: For a function call, the compiler doesn't need to know the full definition; it will have it when it counts, when the function is called.  For a variable declaration it needs the full definition if for no other reason than to know how much space to reserve.

Comment: if every `tile` contains a `tile` then each `tile` contains an infinite number of `tile`s. It just does not make sense. In C++ objects are objects. A `tile` cannot be not a `tile`, so there is no way to break the recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function declaration does not require that its argument types be complete.

```
struct A; 
void f(A); // fine
```

That requirement is only applied at the function definition

```
struct A;
void f(A); // fine
// void f(A) { } // not fine
struct A { };
void f(A) { } // fine
```

There is a special exception for class member functions: the definition of any function inside a class is effectively implicitly split from its declaration and moved out of the class

```
struct A { void f(A) { } /* A is indeed incomplete within its definition */ };
// but f can be defined "within" it anyway because this is made equivalent to
struct A { inline void f(A); };
inline void A::f(A) { } // fine
```

Technically speaking, the *body* (but not declaration) of a class member function is considered a [*complete-class context*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem.general-7). Roughly speaking, the declarations in a class body are not in the complete-class context, so they see the class type as incomplete. However, definitions/initializers associated with those declarations are in complete-class contexts, so they see the class type as complete.